# Reading a filestream using too much memory

Tags: c#, .net, filestream

I want  to read a file  into to stream as a `base64string` and I am using the below code to read the file , but when i see the memory usage is shooting over 900MB, when I monitor it through the task Manager. am I missing something, I could see that the memory usage shoots up when I read it into the string ,(I have used a 150 MB file to test the same).

```
stringBuilder Sb=  new stringBuilder ();
using (var fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\Sanath Kumar\Desktop\s.pdf", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    var buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
    fs.Read(buffer, 0, (int)fs.Length);
    Sb.Append(Convert.ToBase64String(buffer));
    buffer = null;
    fs.Flush();
    fs.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is you are reading the file in it's entirety into memory and duplicating the data several times.

- The `byte[]` array
- The `StringBuilder` which has a `char[]` backing array

If this file is of a significant size this will definitely cause a spike in memory.

Instead of reading it all in at once try using the `ToBase64Transform` class instead.  This is designed to work with a `Stream` as input and will avoid loading the entire file into memory at one time.  Instead it will process it in chunks.

Comment: hey JaredPar,
i have used the code in the link , http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.tobase64transform(v=vs.110).aspx , and instead of writing to the outfile, i appeneded into a string , but its takes forever for the code to execute

Comment: since i want the complete  base64Encoded string data in the memory at once, the above solution does not seem to work for me , is there any other alternative